Trying to install Ubuntu on an Acer ES1-531-C0XK
I'm trying to install on an Acer ES1-531-C0XK. Install proceeds as expected but on the final reboot "system reset" appears on the top left of the black screen and the laptop shuts down, starts again and does the same thing over & over again. Any ideas how to remedy this?
Thanks
